# github api : List workflow runs with created and status parameters

Tags: python, github, github-api

I am trying to list Lists all workflow runs for a repository with parameters created and status also i am using per_page. I am using below url but it doss not work as expected. It does not throw any error but the filter for date(created)does not work. I can see workflows with date 2022-08-02T09:29:07Z as well.
But i am trying to do it in python as well

```
curl \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>" \
  https://<base url>/api/v3/repos/<org>/<repo>/actions/runs\
  ?q=status:completed+created:>=2022-10-10&per_page=100

import requests
u= f"https://<base url>/api/v3/repos/<org>/<repo>/actions/runs?q=status:completed+created:>=2022-10-10&per_page=100"

res = requests.get(u, headers={"Authorization": "Bearer <TOKEN>",
         "Accept": "application/vnd.github+json"})
```

Comment: What do you mean with "it does not work as expected"? Are you getting an error? If so, please add it to your question.

Comment: I am not getting any error but the filter for date(created) does not work. i can see workflows with date 2022-08-02T09:29:07Z as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/workflow-runs#list-workflow-runs-for-a-repository), it looks like `created` should be a query parameter itself.

Try: `runs?status=completed&created=>=2022-10-10&per_page=100`